# Inspite of 'if' command,selecting values only from school id 1

Tags: php

By using below mentioned commands,if school id is 1 or 3,these code only picking values from  if ($sch = "1")......

```
$xyz5 = mysql_query("select id from schools where id='UserSchool'");
$xyz6 = mysql_fetch_row($xyz5);
$sch = $xyz6[0];

if ($sch = "1") {
    $xyz = mysql_query("select phone from students where student_id='$student_id'");
    $xyz2 = mysql_fetch_row($xyz);
    $pno = $xyz2[0];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sms_fees (STUDENT_ID,SCHOOL_ID,MESSAGE,assigned_date,phone)
    values('".$student_id."', '".UserSchool()."', '".str_replace("\'","'
        '",$_REQUEST['
        MESSAGE '])."', '".DBDate()."', '".$pno."')
    ";
    DBQuery($sql);
}

elseif($sch = "3") {
    $xyz1 = mysql_query("select phone from students where student_id='$student_id'");
    $xyz12 = mysql_fetch_row($xyz1);
    $pno1 = $xyz12[0];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sms_fees (STUDENT_ID,SCHOOL_ID,MESSAGE,assigned_date,phone)
    values('".$student_id."', '".UserSchool()."', '".str_replace("\'","'
        '",$_REQUEST['
        MESSAGE '])."', '".DBDate()."', '".$pno1."')
    ";
    DBQuery($sql);
}
```

Comment: Your '=' should probably be replaced by '=='.

Comment: what on earth is going on with the variable names $xyz1, $xyz2..... etc - makes it hard to interpret

Comment: I don't think that your logic is correct. In query, you mentioned `id='UserSchool'` but in condition `id` seems '1'  (see `if ($sch = "1")`).

Comment: @ raveenanigam   ...if my school id is 1,it need to fetch values from  ($sch = "1") and if my school id=3 it need to fetch values from  ($sch = "3") ...but by using these commands its only fetching values from school id 1..

Comment: Please use speaking variable names. Code with variables like `xyz`,`pon`,`sch` and so on is very very hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

It will never matches to 1. Please see your query

```
$xyz5=mysql_query("select id from schools where id='UserSchool'");
```

You are selecting `id` where `id='UserSchool'`
So the below code never matches to "1"

```
if ($sch = "1") {
```

Correct your query first.

Answer (score 1):

You must use double equal sign! Your conditions are assignments and are always evaluating to true (non empty strings), so conditions other than first are ignored.

Change it to that:

```
if ($sch == "1") {
```

Or even to that if you know your variable is always string not int:

```
if ($sch === "1") {
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "=="

```
if ($sch == "1") {
if ($sch == "3") {
```

The reason why it is entering first `if` condition is because you are assigning 1 to $sch and `if` evaluates to true, hence the control enters the first `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
if ($sch == "1") 
{
    // do something
}
elseif($sch == "3")
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something
}
```